# Rails 4.2 and cross-domain cookies to allow reading of cookie data

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cookies

I have a Rails 4.2 app that is getting requests from another domain. I'd like them to send a uuid that we set in our javascript. It works on localhost but not cross-domain. In our application_controller.rb I have:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

 after_filter :cors_set_access_control_headers

  def cors_set_access_control_headers
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, PUT, DELETE, GET, OPTIONS'
    headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
  end
```

but I am not able to get a value like:

```
cookies[:uuid]
```

Is there another step I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Without your logs, I don't have any specific recommendations.

However, you'll be much better using the [`Rack::CORS`](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) gem. This provides middleware which makes the permission of CORS requests much simpler:

```
#Gemfile
gem "rack-cors"

#config/application.rb
config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
  allow do
     origins '*'
     resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :options]
   end
end
```

This will permit *any* request (origin) to *any* resource - it's much better to use specifics in the above (IE `origins "google.com"`).

This should fix your CORS issue for you.